# Is this a redundant null check?

Tags: sql

I keep seeing SQL like this in the where clauses of various stored procedures:

```
((@ActivityID is null) or ((@ActivityID is not null) and (d.ActivityID = @ActivityID)))
```

Is there any reason to check the nullity of `@ActivityID` twice? Or can it be simplified as

```
((@ActivityID is null) or (d.ActivityID = @ActivityID))
```

?

Comment: Correct. `is not null` isn't needed.

Comment: Yes it is redundant. I see the same code too somethings though and I often think that it's put there just for readability. You can actually see the sentence that programmer/DBA was saying in his head while writing that code :-)

Comment: Personally I dislike redundant parentheses more than redundant null checks

Comment: I agree, I don't like the redundant parentheses either...